# How can i test service with ngRedux

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-services

How can i mock getState of ngRedux: with karma jasmine

For example my service get value from store by ngRedux.

```
this.ngRedux.getState()
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by spying on the getState() method:

```
spyOn(MockNgRedux.getInstance(), 'getState').and.returnValue({ ... });
```

I have no idea if that's the way to do it, but it worked in my case. I don't need to mock any fancy state modifications, though, just one simple getState().

`MockNgRedux` is part of the `@angular-redux/store` module. Your test could look somewhat like this:

```
...
import {MockNgRedux, NgReduxTestingModule} from '@angular-redux/store/lib/testing';

describe('MyTest', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            ...
            imports: [
                ...
                NgReduxTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                ...
                MockNgRedux
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    it('does something', () => {
        // set up
        spyOn(MockNgRedux.getInstance(), 'getState').and.returnValue({here: 'be my mock store'});
        spyOn(MockNgRedux.getInstance(), 'dispatch').and.stub();
        ....
        expect(MockNgRedux.getInstance().dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(something);
    });
});
```

Here's a link to the docs: https://angular-redux.github.io/store/classes/mockngredux.html

Comment: what is MockNgRedux?

Comment: Cannot find module '@angular-redux/store/lib/testing'. anything that you installed using npm install in order to access this?

Comment: I did not have to install anything in particular. What version have you got? For me it worked with version 6.5.7. One thing to note: I'm using yarn instead of npm. Though I can't imagine that this should make a difference ...

Comment: It's "@angular-redux/router": "6.1.0",
    "@angular-redux/store": "6.1.0",

Comment: @fritteli Is there a way we can test without using 6.5.7 version?

Comment: Hm, try importing like this: `import { NgReduxTestingModule, MockNgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store/testing';`, as seen here: https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/intro-tutorial.md#unit-testing-selections If that works, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Did it work out in the end? If so, you could accept my answer, so that future searchers for the same problem will find a solution more quickly!