# How to write test case for NgRedux

Tags: angular, junit, karma-jasmine

I am a beginner to Angular Unit Test Case writing. I want to write a unit test case for following code segment. How can I write this.

> this.ngRedux.getState().message.data

Answer (score 0):

According to this [@ngrx page](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing), I'd go with:

```
store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
store.getState().message.data
```

```
describe('Auth Guard', () => {
  let guard: AuthGuard;
  let store: MockStore;
  const initialState = { loggedIn: false };
 
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ // any modules needed
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
        // other providers
      ],
    });
 
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    guard = TestBed.inject(AuthGuard);
  });
 
  it('should get data state', () => {
    const expected = cold('(a|)', { a: false });
    store.setState({ message : {data : [1, 3, 7]} });
    expect(store.getState().message.data).toEqual([1, 3, 7]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I could not import this line.                                                      import { provideMockStore, MockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';

Comment: You might be using ng-redux instead of ngrx then. Do you know what lib you have installed?

Comment: I have found this: it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181718/how-can-i-test-service-with-ngredux

Comment: I followed that post also. I want to know how to call message.data part. Because there is an issue after spyOn (according to mentioned post)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this issue. We can write the spyOn as below

```
spyOn(MockNgRedux.getInstance(), 'getState').and.returnValues({
            message: {
                data: {} 
            } 
 });
```

This method works for me.